# access private constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I want only A can create B. (I also want to export otherAPIs method in header file.)
but I can't put B constructor into private. is there a way to work around my question?
thanks.

```
class B
{
private:
B()
{ // doing something}
public:
void otherAPIs()
{}
};

class A
{
public:
B *getSomething()
{ //doing something
   return new B()} 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want `A` to create `B`, you can make `A` a friend of `B` by adding `friend class A;` in the body of the declaration of `B`.

Comment: He also needs to change the access specifier from private to protected?

Comment: Nope. Friends can access everything about you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `friends class` to do this as MSN said.

If you just want `A` to create `B`. You can define `B`'s interface as abstract, and put the concrete implementation of `B` and implementation of `A` in cpp file, so the implementation thus the constructor of `B` is not accessible to the user of the class. User can only create `B` object through `A`.

In your header file:

```
class BInterface {
public:
    // Methods declared here as abstract.
    virtual void some_method() = 0;
};
class A {
public:
    BInterface * create_b();
};
```

In your cpp file:

```
class B : public BInterface {
public:
    B() {
        // stuff here 
    }
    virtual void some_method() {
        // stuff here.
    }
};
BInterface * A::create_b() {
    return new B(); // something like this.
}
```

Comment: it works too. for LINE A (A::create_b()), it return a type BInterface instead of B. do you think it will cause confusion that people was expecting Binterface object instead of object B?

Comment: @cppython Actually I think it will make "I don't want you to have full construct access to `class B`" clearer. :)

Comment: by the way, may I ask which method (MSN or you) are better or popular?  I really want to use the standard one.

Comment: @cppython That really depends on your intention. If you just want a simple way to restrict access to constructor while allowing access to another class, use `friend`. The method I provided is more complex, and it also hides the implementation of `B` from user, while it allows polymorphic `B` object too. If that's also what you want use this.

Comment: yes, it is more complex and more powerful too. if I have B,C and D classes , I can hide all of them under XInterface.

Comment: @cppython People would say it's separating implementation from interface (There's also pimpl idiom that can do this). I don't know a fancy name. :D